# Reuse of future in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, promise, future

I would like to shutdown a thread with a future:

```
   do
    {
      periodic_or_on_notify();
      next += delta;
    }
   while(future.wait_until(next) != std::future_status::ready);

   shutdown();
```

The thread should perform its activity periodically or upon notification by another thread.

The future could have two different integer values for shutdown and notification,
but I read that futures are single use only.
Is replacing the future/promise possible? What if the promise is replaced, before it's future is read?

Is there an easier way with C++11?

Comment: What do you mean by *I would like to shutdown a thread with a future*? A future is just something to catch the return value of an asynchronous computation.

Comment: If the promise associated with the future is set, the above thread will stop looping a go to shutdown.